# Question on conditional distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I have three random variables, $X,Y,Z$. If I know that $X|Y,Z \sim N(0,1)$, can I claim that $X|Y \sim N(0,1)$? If not, is there anything I can say about $X|Y$?

Comment: What's the meaning of $X| Y$?

Comment: @littleO the distribution of $X$ conditional on $Y$.